# How to customize ZXingScannerView border

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using [barcodescanner library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) in my project, I need to customize the border color of ZXingScannerView.
as you can see in the below image the default color is green, how to change the border color?
is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: @ChrisStillwell How to make `laser` moving up and down with `ZXingScanner ` please update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to find this file in your library and edit viewfinder_border.

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/core/src/main/res/values/colors.xml

Comment: Thank you, but how to access I just add a url in gradle ??

Comment: I think it's not possible. You have to change color of ViewFinderView and there is a method "setBorderColor()" in this class, but field ViewFinderView is private in BarcodeScannerView.class, so you don't have access there. Maybe there is a another way.

Comment: Actually you can override the color in your own colors.xml file i.e.<color name="viewfinder_border">#00d1cf</color>

Comment: Where can I find another colors and properties I can override? I've got the same problem - I installed it by adding gradle.

Comment: Ok, I found it: `viewfinder_border`, `viewfinder_laser`, `viewfinder_mask`. One thing is weird - I cannot set transparent color for the border.

Comment: @codddeer123 I have same problem,wt can i do for solve it?

Comment: It's not necessary override the xml values, you could set the properties like this: 
scannerView.setBorderColor(Color.MAGENTA) or 
scannerView.setLaserColor(Color.GREEN)

Comment: These might not have been there at the time this answer was given. With recent versions of the library you can style it via xml attributes (e.g. laserColor, borderColor, enableLaser, maskColor,...)